# SharePoint online low click through search criteria

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

SharePoint online show popular search queries that received low click-through as abandoned queries. Can someone please help me to understand the exact definition of low click through in SharePoint or mention any MSDN official docs where Microsoft talked about the low click through definition in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

The data of "**popular search queries that received low click-through**" in [search reports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/view-search-usage-reports#overview-of-search-reports) records how many times these search queries have appeared during search and how many of them have not received any click.

The data reflects that, the search results returned by these queries might not be ideal or are not what users are looking for, so that some of them are not being clicked at all.

Admins can build query rules to improve the query's results so that it will improve user satisfaction.

[image]